# meaning of print-plus

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of print-plus in the following text?

> Publish a beta version of the project in a print-plus mode online and establish
>   a workflow to repurpose this content for traditional publication.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.  This appears to be a domain- or product-specific usage; I suggest consulting the author or a guidebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a guess because it's jargon, but I would read it as *everything that the printed version has, plus more*.

So it should have all the content of the printed version (the "traditionally published" version), but it should have extra functionality, like hyperlinks, pop-up notes for clarification, help texts, whatever.

Comment: ELU 'answers' are not for bits of guesses (or complete ones).